# SharePoint Framework (GA): how to prevent rewriting of CSS class names?

Tags: css, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, online

SharePoint Framework currently takes my .scss files and changes all class names by adding IDs like this: `floatRight_789b4d6f`. I understand this is done to isolate the styling within the web part but it messes up styling where I don't control the CSS.

Let's say I'm using an external JavaScript library that generates HTML as well as specific CSS class names (I don't control these). I need to style these elements and therefor cannot use the "mangled" class names the SharePoint Framework gives me. I need to use exactly the class names as they are generated by the external library (so `floatRight`for the above sample).

**Sample**

HTML generated by external library:

```
<div class="floatRight">...</div>
```

Good. I need to style the `floatRight` class.

This is in my scss file:

```
.floatRight {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

But this is generated in the scss.ts file:

```
const styles = {
  floatRight: 'floatRight_789b4d6f'
};
```

And my style is not applied to the element.

**Question**

How to get rid of the IDs? How can I disable this class name rewriting for certain .scss files? Or is there an alternative approach that is recommended here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 1**: Remove the ".module" from your file name to disable rewriting of CSS class names.

See here for details: http://www.n8d.at/blog/how-to-handle-automatic-css-class-renaming-in-spfx/

**Update 2**: There is now official documentation about these so-called "CSS modules" and the .module extension: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/css-recommendations#use-css-modules-to-avoid-styling-conflicts

---

The solution for me was to add a **new** scss file to my project. The styles from this new scss file are not extended with IDs.

The (complete) generated scss.ts file looks like this:

```
/* tslint:disable */
require('./NameOfMyFile.css');

/* tslint:enable */
```

That's it. No `styles` variable. No IDs.

I include the style file in my view model like this:

```
require('./NameOfMyFile.scss');
```

All good.

Comment: That wormks great! Thanks. Way easier than loading from a cdn

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping your CSS in a `:global` block like this:

```
:global {
    .floatRight {
        float: right;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Is there documentation on this somewhere you can point me to? Just want to understand if this will have any downstream effects

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been in this space for a few years now. Looking at the other answers, it appears that the framework is using CSS modules. I do see mentions of :global in the CSS modules repo (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SPComponentLoader.loadCss` method to load your external css files.

Add the below import statement:

```
import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';
```

After that in your constructor, you can use it as below:

```
public constructor() {
 super();    
 SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
}
```

This will load the css as it is and you can use the class names that are provided by the external library.

Comment: The CSS file will be part of my bundle. Is this method applicable for CSS files contained in the (webpack) bundle?

Comment: Yes i think it should work. Just ensure that css path is valid.

Comment: It does not seem to work for modules, or some additional action is required to add CSS files as modules :-/